# Index.php doesn't work on VPS but other files do

Tags: php, apache, debian, vps

I've got really interesting problem with my VPS.

I've already installed www server using this instructions set: http://wiki.debian.org/LaMp and everything looks fine, but index.php file doesn't work.

It's main file of whole service and it's contains some initializations and includes. When I add there some echo, it display correctly. It seems that include function doesn't work.

Phpmyadmin works fine, other php files works but no index.php. I'm pretty sure it's not problem with file because it works great on old hosting.

Any ideas? I've searched the net, reinstalled everything twice but still i don't have any solution and i'm starting to feel helpless. If you need some additional information - ask.

Comment: What's in the index.php? Given the echoes work, what does the file DO otherwise?

Comment: Try a require istead of an include, you should receive an error-message. Are you sure that the path for include is correct?

Comment: It's include some other files, start session etc. I'll try to use require. I'm sure because as i said before it works fine on old hosting and it adressed relative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My main guess is, that it throws an error which is not displayed.

Try adding this to the top of your PHP file:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

that should show you all the errors.

alternatively, you can check your error-log